# How to clear document values when opening a dialog the second time

Tags: modal-dialog, xpages

On a document I have a button that opens a model dialog (in this case a bootstrap modal) this dialog creates a new document and I the user enters some info then clicks a send button that saves the and closes the dialog. This works fine, but if the user needs to create a second document via the dialog in the same session of the main document the second dialog loads with the values from the first one. I have tried just about everything I can think of using the queryOpen postOpen and onClient load events to clear the fields and set them to a new set of defaults. It all works but only if you only create one dialog document per session of the main Document (ie close the main doc and re-open it.

Comment: If you bound the fields to sessionScope then this will happen?  If you did this, try using viewScope instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a Document Data Source for the dialog? If so, then in its properties, set the scope property to "request".

The default is "view", which is why the values remain unless you refresh the XPage.

Comment: I don't see where in the Data Source to set the scope property. Here is my Data Source :
<xp:this.data>
 <xp:dominoDocument var="reqDoc"
  ignoreRequestParams="true">
  <xp:this.databaseName><![CDATA[#{appProps[sessionScope.ssApplication].appFilePath}]]></xp:this.databaseName>
  <xp:this.formName><![CDATA[#{javascript:"frmInfoRequest"}]]></xp:this.formName>


 </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>

I don'r see a place for the scope on a datasource

Comment: Found it didn't go deep enough.

Comment: When I set the dataSource to request now the action behind my send button does not execute. I have a print statment at the very top of the code and it never happens. If I change the scope to view the code works fine. I am using a bootstrap modal and wonder if an xe:dialog would give me a bit more control?

Comment: What SSJS/CSJS code are you running that no longer triggers? If SSJS, Is is partial or full refresh? You might need to paste here a very compact version of your XPage to assist with troubleshooting.

Comment: John -- The problem was with a bootstrap model I could not do a refresh from either the button calling the dialog (just flashes the dialog on and then off) nor with the send button (just dismiss' the dialog without getting to the code on the button).
Switched it to an xe:dialog and call it with a getcomponent("myDialog").show and a partial refresh on the panel displaying the dialog. This of course send a request to the server which resets the request scoped datasource which is what was needed. Now the dialog gets refreshed every time the dialog is called and is doing exactly what I need.

Comment: If I understand it correctly the attrs data-dismiss=modal on the send button triggers before the onClick even so the bootstrap modal gets dismissed before the onClick can execute. So in bootstrap my send button looked like this:
<xp:button value="Send" id="buttonSend" styleClass="btn btn-info">
<xp:this.attrs>
 <xp:attr name="data-dismiss" value="modal">
 </xp:attr>
</xp:this.attrs>
<xp:eventHandler
event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh">
<xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var debug:Boolean = true;
.
'
</xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
maybe a way in BS but...